Why can't I add the script to my Game Object?
So I recently got an asset from the Unity Asset Store that's mean to make ropes, but when I tried to use it, It said it couldn't add the script to the game object?
This was the error:

Can't add script component 'RopeEditor' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match.

And This was the Important part of the code (I think for this error anyways)
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

namespace GogoGaga.OptimizedRopesAndCables
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(Rope))]
    public class RopeEditor : Editor
    {

If anyone could help me understand the problem and help me try to fix that'd be great because I'd rather tamper than try to find something else.

Because it is an editor class not a monobehavior

You want to add the Rope component to your GameObject!
This RopeEditor just controls how the Inspector of that Rope component will then look like.

You can add a script to a GameObject if the class is derived from MonoBehaviour.
In this case:
public class RopeEditor : Editor

The class "RopeEditor" is derived from "Editor". There is probably a script called "Rope" which can be added to your game objects. Good luck!
